# How to avoid repeatedly instantiating an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using reactjs and there is a instantiation in `componentDidUpdate()`. But when update state,  the `componentDidUpdate()` will be execute and the Object will repeat statement

```
ps: const barrage = new Barrage();  the object will be execute repeatly

componentDidUpdate() {
    const barrage = new Barrage();
}


const barrage = new Barrage();
```

how to avoid the Object statement repeatly execute

Comment: This is my first time to ask a question

Comment: Yes it will create instance on every update. But whether you want to create new instance or not on every update would depend upon your requirements. Please clarify what exactly you want to do with this variable and then appropriate answer can be given.

Comment: I don't want create new instance on every update

Answer (score 1):

you haven't really explained what you want to achieve but I will try to solve this specific question by saying you can put it in a state if you need it to create new instance only once

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);   
  ...
  this.state = {
     barrage : null
   }
  ...
}

 componentDidUpdate(prevState) {
  if(!prevState.barrage) {
    this.setState({ barrage : new Barrage() )}
  }
}
```

Comment: why not move it to `componentDidMount`?

Comment: I need use this variable in componDidUpdate. eg:  barrage.play();

Comment: you can still access it, from componentDidUpdate, just save it in a state.

Comment: No I'm saying in `componentDidMount` save barrage in state and access it in `componentDidUpdate`, like `this.state.barrage`

Answer (score 1):

You could create it in `componentDidMount` and cleanup in `componentWillUnmount`

```
class TestComponent extends React.Component {
  barage = null;

  componentDidMount() {
    this.barage = new Barage();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.barage = null;
  }
}
```

It's really hard to guess what you're doing with that object without any code. I can only assume that it is independent of the updates to the component, if any.